# Rendered image saving as blank image

Tags: rendering, image, volumetrics, saving

I rendered volume ok, but it saves as a blank image. I've tried save-as PNG and exr and also tried the output in compositor. When I render as a combined image the volume acts as expected, however there is no image information if I render a VolDir/VolInd pass.  The volume on its own layer with the other objects on 'hold out'. I just dont understand why I can't save what I see.[image]

Comment: please provide blend file because this could have a lot of reasons e.g. object in the way, visibility flags etc

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for the reply, I only just spotted it - sorry. In the project I've tried a few output methods so the compositor is a bit littered and there are scenes that are not being rendered but may perhaps have something to do with the visibility issue. To render the volume I  was using the render button on the input node in the compositor (after not having success with F12). https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BqfenKgIOq-85EpOMUEKCyhob4bpMohI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Billy, please provide file with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. I will not ask for permission (for your file) to help you. So please use the link so that everybody can learn from your question